# Is there a search engine for renting an electric car?

Tags: online-resources, car-rentals

There are several companies that rent electric cars, and there are several websites that compare companies that rent Internal Combustion Engine (ICE) cars.  But are there websites that compare electric car rentals, given date and place (or, alternately, existing car rental comparisons with an "electrical" checkbox)?

Comment: I would wonder if one of the ordinary rental search sites has a way to filter for electric vehicles.  I know Kayak has a "hybrid" check box.

Comment: If you don't insist on a traditional rental company, you might try something like Turo where individuals rent out their cars. There you get a specific car, versus a broad category.

Comment: I would also recommend Turo(since the previous comment didn't describe it, it's basically AirBnb for cars), it's really easy to use. The only thing is, that individual owners seem to want to charge a premium for electric cars. I tried it in San-Diego, it was $80/day for a Tesla model-3 long range and $40/day for a Bmw I-3, whereas a Nissan Versa was $18/day. I thought it worth the money, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Eugene One would have to save >22$/day on fuel which is difficult when fuel is as cheap as in the USA...

Comment: @gerrit (1) Actually no, since when travelling, you can't charge your car at home. E.g. for the Tesla model 3, I had to return the car charged(same as gas cars, but shouldn't be IMHO) and Tesla superchargers cost(from their website): $ 0.26 per minute above 60 kW/
$ 0.13 per minute at or below 60 kW. What sucks is that there's no price difference between the V1(72kw), V2(125kw) and V3(250kw).

Comment: @gerrit (2) I charged at a V1 supercharger(San Diego - Friars Road) and I got charged about 20 bucks on top of the rental for the Supercharger usage. Oh and I had to wait about an hour and a half for the whole thing(not a problem, made plans to visit a restaurant while charging). Still very worth it, it was a really cool car, but electric cars are definitely NOT cheap or convenient for rentals.

Comment: @Eugene The [local electric cars near me](https://www.einfachcarsharing.de/) cost €2/hour to rent for customers of the electricity company owning them, or €5/hour otherwise, and they just need to be plugged in when returned. Getting a car for two hours to go to a shop and back and paying only €4 (or even €10) for it and no fuel seems like a pretty good deal to me.  I think there's special deals for longer rentals.

Comment: @gerrit Ah, my bad for implicit US-centrism. What kinds of cars are available on that deal?

Comment: @Eugene It's an e-Golf

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For example, even just in New Zealand, [Europecar](https://www.europcar.co.nz/electric-vehicles) has a option, and [Thrifty](https://www.thrifty.co.nz/electric-vehicles/) does at two of the airports.